# Load user control and handle post back in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls, updatepanel, postback

I'm working with ASP.NET 3.5 C#

I've seen a good few questions like this around but havn't actually come across any articles with the answer (maybe just been unlucky with my research!).

Basically I'm looking to have say 3 links (or buttons) on a page, which in turn will dynamically load a specific user control into an update panel with AJAX.

Then I would like the usercontrol loaded to be capable of handling postback within the update panel (basically no page refreshes) to do its processing and return output.

Is this possible?

Does anyone have any pointers to articles/blogs covering this?

I've seen many, but none covered handling postbacks from the user control or handling the postbacks within the update panel.

I may even have the wrong end of the stick here.

Any tips would be great to start me off :)

Cheers!

Comment: Embed the UserControls in separate UpdatePanels and handle all that belong to them inside. If you must add or remove them update the outer UpdatePanel.

Comment: Id be doing it dynamically & wouldnt know how many controls would be used. Is it possible to do dynamically with one update panel?

Comment: If your user controls are loaded dynamically, have you made sure that they are reloaded properly during the postback _before_ ViewState is processed?

Comment: Probably it's what TLS said, but dynamically loading usercontrols is one of those things that seems like a good idea at the time, but always seems to result in all sorts of event-order headaches. If it's only 3 different ones, I would just include them all in the markup, and set visibility state as needed.

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at this blog post](http://samuelmueller.com/2008/12/dynamicloader-plugin-dynamically-loading-asp-net-user-controls-with-jquery).

It may not be exactly what you want (Postback issue), but can be a good alternative solution to get started with.